Hello Everyone ! i want to connect webSocket to my mern app but getting some error
i am working on realtime chat-app ... want to integrate websocket for instance chat ... but i am getting the error i am getting this kind of error (socket__io-client.js?v=6fe409f1:1018 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed: ) ...
=======> my source code on react <========
`
if (userInfo) {

  const socket = io("http://localhost:5000", {

    transports: ["websocket"],

  });

  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Connected:", socket.id);
  });

  setSocket(socket);
  return () => {
    socket.close();
  };
}

i read the webSocket Doc but didn't findout the solution and they also did on the same way ... may the error is about the connection ..

You can clarify your question by adding the code of your entire file.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
